# Using function declared in C++ dll and its VB declarations

Tags: c++

There is a .dll and .lib file for the evaluation board AD5501 after installing its drivers. It contains the functions to use to connect to the board and send instructions to it.

A quick search in analog's website (https://ez.analog.com/thread/11121) revealed a document that contains the commands in the above mentioned DLL file. And it is mentioned that the DLL is written in C++. At the end of the page there is a pdf containing VB6 function declarations of the DLL.

I have no knowledge of VB6 but the fact that the DLL has been written in C++ led me to assume that I should be able to access the function in the DLL or LIB file if i know the function prototype in a C++ program. Is this a correct assumption?

And the website has description of the function prototype. So i made a test C++ program as given below :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


unsigned int Search_For_Boards (unsigned int VID, unsigned int PID, unsigned int *Num_boards, char *PartPath[]);
int Connect(unsigned int VID, unsigned int PID, char PartPath, unsigned int *Handle);
int Download_Firmware(unsigned int Handle, char  pcFilePath[]);
int Vendor_Request(unsigned int  Handle, unsigned char Request, unsigned short Value, unsigned short Index,  unsigned char Direction, unsigned short DataLength, unsigned char *Buffer[]);
int Disconnect (unsigned int Handle);

int main(){
    char *partpath[2];
    unsigned int *num;
    unsigned int vid = 1110;
    unsigned int pid = 45617;

    unsigned int error = Search_For_Boards(vid, pid, num,  partpath);

    cout<<"Hello\n"<<error<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And on compiling the code in the following command:

```
g++ C:\test.cpp -L "C:\Program Files\Analog Devices\USB Drivers" -lADI_CYUSB_USB4
```

I get the error

```
Undefined reference to Search_For_Boards(unsigned int, unsigned, int, unsigned int*, char**)
```

meaning apparently the function prototype is not correct.

Now all this is ASSUMING that i can use the DLL in a C++ program. Seeing the document for VB6 function declaration made me thinking if my assumption is wrong. So my 2 questions are :

1) Is my assumption correct?

2) If the assumption is correct, What is the blunder i am doing here? I feel like I linked the library properly and to my best declared the prototype according to what is described.

Comment: Does declaring your prototypes `extern` change anything ?

Comment: @Fluffy No. I get the same Undefined reference error with the prototypes being declared as 'extern'

Comment: Used DLL Export Viewer to check if the function names are at least matching. Turns out it is. This screenshot https://imgur.com/a/yLcLhSh shows the various names of the functions available in the above discussed DLL...

Comment: Yeah I don't see what's wrong with your approach.. something that crossed my mind though: make sure you're not mixing x86 with x64 code, compiling with `-m32` or `-m64` to match your library arch might be necessary. In addition, use the `-v` switch to make the linker more verbose and look for a lead there

Comment: Looking at your screen cap, your DLL addresses are on 32 bits, so there's that

Comment: @Fluffy I am using mingw 32-bit compiler for compiling the program. Initially I installed the 64 bit compiler as my system is 64 bits. But when i try compiling with 64 bit version g++, Incompatible library error occurs. So changed to 32 bit compiler and the incompatible error doesn't occur. So having a -m32 option wouldn't matter probably because compiler itself is 32 bits.

Adding verbose output is not helping. At the last of a very large output info is the same Undefined Reference error with no extra information about that.